# Efficient Method for Calculating the Probability of a Set of Outcomes?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let's say I'm playing N different independent "games". For each game, I know the probability of winning, the probability of tying, and the probability of losing.

From these values, I've also calculated the probability of winning exactly X games, the probability of tying exactly X games, and the probability of losing exactly X games (for X = 0 to N).

I'm just trying to figure out the probability of each outcome after playing all N games. For example, if N = 10, what is the probability of winning 7, losing 2, and tying 1?

Any ideas, or a proof that this is impossible to compute efficiently?

Comment: Have you read the faq? I don't think this is a question of interest to research mathematicians. 

Comment: you might try posting your question to 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/

they seem to deal with more basic stuff as well. [altho i'm not sure how "basic" you question actually is. i suppose with statistical software the answer for any particular outcome can be computed. maybe you want to ask about appropriate software for doing the required calculations.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question so it asks for an *efficient* means of calculating the probability of each outcome (or a proof that there is no efficient way), if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Bjørn: updated, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Answer (score 0):

Excel (or any spreadsheet) is your friend for this calculation.  In rows 1-3 of each column you put the probabilities of a win, tie, and loss in that game.  To ease the following, in rows 4-6 put in the probability of a nonwin, nontie, and nonloss in that game.  Then in rows 7-7+11^3=1338 you put the probability of having won/lost/tied a number of games (0-10) so far.  If you are clever in the organization, you can just copy down and right a lot. Certainly once you have the second  column you can just copy right.  Look in column J,  row 712+6=718 for the answer.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what would go in rows 7-1338?  You can assume there are only 2 games to keep in simple.  Therefore the possible outcomes are (W-L-T): (2-0-0), (1-1-0). (1-0-1-). (0-1-1). (0-2-0). (0-0-2)

Comment: Each row represents a number of games won, lost and tied. So I confused you because it should be 3^11=177477 rows instead of 11^3=1331.  And Excel won't do that many. At the start, the probability of (0-0-0) is 1.  Let pn(win) be the probability of winning game n.  pn(loss) is the probability of losing game n.  Then the probability of (1-0-0) is p(0-0-0)*p1(win).  The probability of (1-1-0) is p(1-0-0)*p2(loss)+p(0-1-0)*p2(win).  
The message in problems like this is to lose the info you don't need.  After game 5, you don't need to know which games were won,lost,drawn-just how many